# How does $a^{a^n}$ compare with $n!$ asymptotically?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, exponentiation, factorial

I am learning Asymptotic complexity of functions from CLRS. I know that exponentiation functions like $a^n$,$(a>0)$ are faster than $n!$ But what about $a^{a^n}$ vs $n!$ How do they compare? A proof would really help me understand the concept. Thanks!

Comment: Your solution is correct. Ignore the one listed below (as of right now)... it’s incorrect.

Comment: I am thinking of adding my solution as an answer. Should I @cdipaolo?

Comment: Sure, go for it

Comment: You mean that $a^n $ is slower to grow that $n! $, right? In fact, for all $a $ real $\dfrac {a^n}{n!} $ tends to $0$ for n going to infinity. However,  $\dfrac {a^{a^n}}{n!} $ tends to $+ \infty $.

Comment: Since $n!=e^{\Omega(n\ln n)}$ and $a^{a^n}=e^{(\ln a)a^n}$, we can compare exponents, in which case $n\ln n$ is way smaller than $a^n$, so $n!$ is way way ... way = (way)$^n$ smaller than $a^{a^n}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do they compare?: $n!=\mathcal{O}(a^{a^n})$

Proof:
If we bring down both $n!$ and $a^{a^n}$ to $log$ scale then $n!$ in $log$ scale will be approximately $nlogn$ (as $log(n!)≈nlogn$ using Stirling's approximation) and $a^{a^n}$ will be brought down to $a^n*loga$.

$nlogn$ grows slower than $a^n*loga$ which implies $n!=\mathcal{O}(a^{a^n})$.

Comment: You are right that $n\log n$ grows slower than $a^n\log a$, for any $a>1$. Therefore $n!$ grows slower than $a^{a^n}$. In terms of o-notation, this means $n!=o(a^{a^n})$, and therefore $n!=O(a^{a^n})$ and $a^{a^n}=\Omega(n!)$.

Comment: @Andreas Blass thanks for pointing out my mistake! I hope everything is correct now

Answer (score 2):

> Applying $\ln\circ\ln$ we   obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \ln\left(\ln\left(a^{a^n}\right)\right)
> &=\ln\left(a^n\ln    a\right)\\
> &=\ln a^n+\ln\left(\ln\left(a\right)\right)\\
> &=n\ln   a+\ln\left(\ln\left(a\right)\right)\\
> &\sim n\ln  a\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Recalling Stirlings formula $n!\sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$ we obtain

> \begin{align*}
> \ln\left(\ln\left(n!\right)\right)&\sim\ln\left(\ln\left(\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}\right)\right)\\
> &=\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n+\ln\sqrt{2\pi   n}\right)\\
> &=\ln\left(n\ln n-n+\ln\sqrt{2\pi}+\ln n\right)\\
> &\sim \ln\left(n\ln n\right)\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

We conclude from (1) and (2)

> \begin{align*}
> \ln\left(n\ln n\right)=\mathcal{O}\left(n\ln  a\right)
> \end{align*}
>   from which
>   \begin{align*}
> \ln\left(\ln\left(n!\right)\right)=\mathcal{O}\left(\ln\ln    a^{a^n}\right)
> \end{align*}
>   and finally
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{n!=\mathcal{O}\left(a^{a^n}\right)}
> \end{align*}
>   follows.